# Rational display with Quantity

Tags: formatting

Why is that `Power[Quantity["ElectricConstant"],-1]`
 is represent different of 
`Power[Pi,-1]`
What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: The technical "why" can be seen here: `Power[Quantity["ElectricConstant"], -1] // FullForm`. I'm unsure how to prevent this though.

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet a real answer as I offer no solution, only observations.

Attempting to answer this by spelunking `Quantity` formatting is like falling down the rabbit hole.  One internal function leads to another ad infinitum.  I shall stop for now with the observation that the Box formatting comes from this function:

```
CalculateScan`UnitScanner`Private`UnitInformation
```

For example:

```
Quantity["ElectricConstant"]^-2 // FullForm
```

> ```
> Quantity[1,Power["ElectricConstant",-2]]
> ```

Which in the course of box formatting eventually becomes a call like:

```
CalculateScan`UnitScanner`Private`UnitInformation[
 1, 
 QuantityUnits`Private`toAlphaUnit["ElectricConstant"^-2], 
 "SingularTest" -> (MatchQ[#1, 1] &), 
 "Output" -> {"PrefixBoxes", "PostfixBoxes", "UnitBoxes", "DefaultStyle"}
]
```

> ```
> {"", RowBox[{"\"/\"", "\[InvisibleSpace]", 
>    SubsuperscriptBox["\"\[CurlyEpsilon]\"", "0", "2"]}], "", Automatic}
> ```

Observe the `RowBox` with the `"/"`.  This is used in the higher level call:

```
QuantityUnits`Private`QuantityAbbreviation[1, "ElectricConstant"^-1]
```

> ```
> StyleBox[RowBox[{#1, "\[InvisibleSpace]", 
>    StyleBox[RowBox[{"\"/\"", "\[InvisibleSpace]", 
>       SubscriptBox["\"\[CurlyEpsilon]\"", "0"]}], "QuantityUnitTraditionalLabel"]}], 
>  ShowStringCharacters -> False]
> ```

Which defines (part of) a formatting function for the expression, which can be observed with:

```
Quantity["ElectricConstant"]^-2 // ToBoxes
```

> ```
> TemplateBox[{"1"}, "QuantityUnit", 
>  DisplayFunction -> (TooltipBox[
>      StyleBox[RowBox[{#1, "\[InvisibleSpace]", 
>         StyleBox[RowBox[{"\"/\"", "\[InvisibleSpace]", 
>            SubsuperscriptBox["\"\[CurlyEpsilon]\"", "0", "2"]}], 
>          "QuantityUnitTraditionalLabel"]}], ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
>      "Unit: per electric constants squared"] &), 
>  InterpretationFunction -> (RowBox[{"Quantity", "[", 
>       RowBox[{#1, ",", FractionBox["1", SuperscriptBox["\"ElectricConstant\"", "2"]]}], 
>       "]"}] &), SyntaxForm -> Mod]
> ```

As you can see this is all rather complicated.  Perhaps later I will continue spelunking to trace the source of the formatting produced by `` CalculateScan`UnitScanner`Private`UnitInformation `` but at the moment I am fatigued.

Comment: It looks like the formatting for reciprocal units comes from `ToPerBox` and `ToSlashBox` in ``CalculateScan`UnitScanner`Private``.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't doing anything wrong, it's just that *Mathematica* uses a linear form for the units in `Quantity` expressions. As mfvonh commented, the expression

```
Power[Quantity["ElectricConstant"], -1]
```

is evaluated to

```
Quantity[1, Power["ElectricConstant", -1]]
```

i.e. a `Quantity` with a magnitude of 1 and units of "reciprocal electric constants". The unit "reciprocal electric constants" is displayed as $1/\varepsilon _0$ just as units like "meters per second" are displayed as $m/s$ rather than the 2D form $\frac{m}{s}$

I am not aware of any simple method to change the way quantity units are formatted (though I would be delighted to be wrong). In principle you could modify the internal code for generating boxes for `Quantity` expressions but, as Mr Wizard has shown, the code is rather complex and it would not be easy.